# How to display data to TextBox after image QR scanned in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm scanning images and when the data is scanned, I would like to transfer or display it to TextBox.

What I've done is scanned it and tried to display it to textbox but it wont display the text.

The result I'm having is that the textbox does not display any data the QR scanned.

Code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if(resultCode  == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        val result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.contents == null)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            else {
                try {
                    // Display this to Textbox
                    val decryptedText = EncryptDecrypt.decrypt(decryptET.text.toString())
                    encryptET.setText(decryptedText)
                } catch (e: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } catch (e: NoSuchPaddingException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } catch (e: IllegalBlockSizeException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } catch (e: BadPaddingException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                } catch (e: InvalidKeyException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this library for this case.

Library - implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.1.0'

Add scaner view in Xml

```
    <com.budiyev.android.codescanner.CodeScannerView
    android:id="@+id/qr_scanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And this is Activity or Fragment code get permission and scan Qr image example

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var codeScanner: CodeScanner

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    codeScanner = CodeScanner(this, binding.qrScanner)



    if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
        codeScanner.startPreview()
    } else {
        permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }

    codeScanner.decodeCallback = DecodeCallback {
        runOnUiThread {
            //Get text it.text and put in TextBox
            println(it.text)
        }
    }
}


private fun allPermissionsGranted() = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA).all {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, it
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

private val permissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            codeScanner.startPreview()
        } else {
            finish()
        }
    }
```